# WooCommerce - get category for product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

For my WC product pages, I need to add a class to the body tag so that I can perform some custom styling. Here's the function I'm creating for this...

```
function my_add_woo_cat_class($classes) {

    $wooCatIdForThisProduct = "?????"; //help!

    // add 'class-name' to the $classes array
    $classes[] = 'my-woo-cat-id-' . $wooCatIdForThisProduct;
    // return the $classes array
    return $classes;
}

//If we're showing a WC product page
if (is_product()) {
    // Add specific CSS class by filter
    add_filter('body_class','my_add_woo_cat_class');
}
```

...but how do I get the WooCommerce cat ID?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

A WC product may belong to none, one or more WC categories. Supposing you just want to get one WC category id.

```
global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
    break;
}
```

Please look into the meta.php file in the "templates/single-product/" folder of the WooCommerce plugin.

```
<?php echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' ); ?>
```

Comment: Just added this code to "price.php" and when visiting single product page I get this error message: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). Do I do something wrong or is this code incompatible with current WC version?

Comment: Is there a way to exclude certain categories with this?

Comment: This helped me to get the product slug and use it to redirect to category listing after saving a new comment. This was my question if is of any help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42014311/wordpress-get-the-category-returns-empty

Comment: This is amazing. I even put cats in arrays for multiple categories. Excellent answer!

Answer (score 14):

`$product->get_categories()` is deprecated since version 3.0! Use `wc_get_product_category_list` instead.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_product_category_list.html

Comment: 404 on link. sigh

Comment: Working link to the new API: https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/namespaces/default.html#function_wc_get_product_category_list

Comment: Better Example to understand this - https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_get_product_category_list/

Answer (score 9):

I literally striped out this line of code from content-single-popup.php located in woocommerce folder in my theme directory.

```
global $product; 
echo $product->get_categories( ', ', ' ' . _n( ' ', '  ', $cat_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', ' ' );
```

Since my theme that I am working on has integrated woocommerce in it, this was my solution.

Comment: Thank you, it returns category name, how to get category id, instead of its name?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Box. I'm using MyStile Theme and I needed to display the product category name in my search result page. I added this function to my child theme functions.php

Hope it helps others.

```
/* Post Meta */


if (!function_exists( 'woo_post_meta')) {
    function woo_post_meta( ) {
        global $woo_options;
        global $post;

        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $product_cat = $term->name;
            break;
        }

?>
<aside class="post-meta">
    <ul>
        <li class="post-category">
            <?php the_category( ', ', $post->ID) ?>
                        <?php echo $product_cat; ?>

        </li>
        <?php the_tags( '<li class="tags">', ', ', '</li>' ); ?>
        <?php if ( isset( $woo_options['woo_post_content'] ) && $woo_options['woo_post_content'] == 'excerpt' ) { ?>
            <li class="comments"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'woothemes' ), __( '1 Comment', 'woothemes' ), __( '% Comments', 'woothemes' ) ); ?></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'woothemes' ), '<li class="edit">', '</li>' ); ?>
    </ul>
</aside>
<?php
    }
}


?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
   $terms = get_the_terms($product->ID, 'product_cat');
      foreach ($terms as $term) {

        $product_cat = $term->name;
           echo $product_cat;
             break;
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Please provide and accurate description of how this helps answer the OP's question.

Comment: Please read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) - describe your code.

Comment: This is very similar to the accepted answer, except it echoes the category name rather than return the category ID!

Comment: @ban-geoengineering ok)

Answer (score 0):

To add custom classes to the body tag you can use the [**`body_class`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/body_class/) hook.

**To add one** or **more classes** on the product page **based on specific product categories** you can use the Wordpress [**`has_term`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/) function *(to check if a product belongs to that specific product category)*.

For this I created the array `$classes_to_add` where:

- **key**: It can be the product category id (or the slug or the name). Or an array of them. [Read the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/).
- **value**: a string containing the classes to add to the body tag. If you want to add more than one class create a string with multiple values separated by a space (see my example below)

So:

```
// adds a class to the body element based on the product category
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_body_class_based_on_the_product_category' );
function add_body_class_based_on_the_product_category( $classes ) {

    // only on the product page
    if ( ! is_product() ) {
        return $classes;
    }

    // create an array with the ids (or slugs) of the product categories and the respective class (or classes) to add
    $classes_to_add = array(
        30          => 'class-1',
        'cat_slug'  => 'class-2 class-3',
        32          => 'class-4 class-5',
    );

    // if the product belongs to one of the product categories in the array it adds the respective class (or classes)
    foreach ( $classes_to_add as $product_cat => $new_classes ) {
        if ( has_term( $product_cat, 'product_cat', get_the_ID() ) ) {
             $classes[] = $new_classes;
        }
    }    

    return $classes;
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*