# woocommerce: disable payment for certain categories

Tags: php, woocommerce

i need to disable payment for certain categories on my woocommerce website. so far i have found this code, which works but for only 1 category. does anyone know how to make this work for multiple categories? thanks

```
<?php
/*
 * A simple filter to disable a user-specified payment gateway when a product with a user-specified category is added to the shopping cart
 *  - Note:  If multiple products are added and only one has a matching category, it will remove the payment gateway
 * Requires:
 *    payment_NAME : One of the five hardcoded Woocommerce standard types of payment gateways - paypal, cod, bacs, cheque or mijireh_checkout
 *    category_ID :   The ID of the category for which the gateway above will be removed.  Get the ID by clicking on the category under Products -> Categories and reading the "tag_ID" in the address bar
 *                             i.e. http://ubuntu.humble.lan/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=product_cat&tag_ID=20&post_type=product <-- the tag_ID is 20
 * Coded by sean _ at _ techonfoot.com
 * Thanks to boxoft - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303031/woocommerce-get-category-for-product-page
 * Usual free code disclaimer - use at your own risk
 * This code was tested against Woocommerce 2.0.8 and WordPress 3.5.1
 */
function filter_gateways($gateways){

$payment_NAME = 'paypal'; // <--------------- change this
$category_ID = '20';  // <----------- and this

 global $woocommerce;

 foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {
    // Get the terms, i.e. category list using the ID of the product
    $terms = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'product_cat' );
    // Because a product can have multiple categories, we need to iterate through the list of the products category for a match
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        // 20 is the ID of the category for which we want to remove the payment gateway
        if($term->term_id == $category_ID){
               unset($gateways[$payment_NAME]);
                   // If you want to remove another payment gateway, add it here i.e. unset($gateways['cod']);
                    break;
          }
        break;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can modify the code provided above to the following and it should work:

```
function filter_gateways($gateways){

    global $woocommerce;

    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {

        // ID(s) of the category we want to remove gateways from
        $category_ids = array( 12,9 );

        // Get the terms, i.e. category list using the ID of the product
        $terms = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'product_cat' );

        // Because a product can have multiple categories, we need to iterate through the list of the products category for a match
        foreach ($terms as $term) {

            if(in_array($term->term_id,$category_ids)){

                // If you have additional items from a non-restricted category in the cart with a restricted category product the only payment option available for all cart items will be the gateway(s) that haven't been unset.
                // WARNING: If you unset all the gateways users will get a "Sorry, it seems that there are no available payment methods for your state. Please contact us if you require assistance or wish to make alternate arrangements." when trying to checkout!
                unset($gateways['cod']);
                unset($gateways['bacs']);
                unset($gateways['cheque']);
                break;
            }
        break;
        }

    }
    return $gateways;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways','filter_gateways');
```

**Note:** Keep in mind that if you have additional items from a non-restricted category in the cart with a restricted category product the only payment option available for all cart items during checkout will be the gateway(s) that haven't been unset.